# Unable to view images in react-responsive-carousel using <Image> tags

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, sass

unable to use view images in react-responsive-carousel
I'm able to access the images if I'm using them in a div but it doesn't show up in the Carousel.

```
<section>
            <div className={styles.carousel}>
              <Carousel
                showThumbs={false}
                autoPlay={true}
                infiniteLoop={true}
                interval={2500} 
                centerMode={true}
                showArrows={false}
                showStatus={false}
                axis="horizontal"
              >
                <div className={styles.carousel}>
                  <Image
                    src={
                      "/group1.jpeg"
                    }
                    alt="CaterNinja.com Logo"
                    width={200}
                    height={160}
                    sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, (max-width: 1200px) 50vw, 33vw"
                    style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className={styles.carousel}>
                  <Image
                    src={
                      "/group3.jpeg"
                    }
                    alt="CaterNinja.com Logo"
                    width={200}
                    height={160}
                    sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, (max-width: 1200px) 50vw, 33vw"
                    style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
                  />
                </div>
              </Carousel>
            </div>
          </section>
```

I have used `<Image>` tags within the Carousel and set the props in the Carousel tag, the images are located in the public folder but do not show up in the Carousel. I have also made the following imports.

```
import "react-responsive- carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";

import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
```

It should be working but not sure why this is happening.
I'm using HTML, SCSS & react.js

Comment: where path the public folder?  
src={ "/group1.jpeg"  }
adjust the image path with the project directory

Comment: @RahmatHidayat yes, thats already config'd. I'm able to use the image with the exact same tags outside the carousel